# MVC4 - get selected text of dropdown list (located in Partial View) every time it's selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC4. I have dropDown list in Partial View. Partial View worked fine for a while. DropDown is updated with data using Ajax call. Now I need to get text selected in dropDown Every time it is selected, parse it, and populate  fieldS with it (fields are located on the form that contains Partial View). I was trying to use dropDown events, but I don't seem to be able to catch events. What is the proper way to implement the above in MVC4? (I did research online and tried many approaches, nothing seems to work). Here is my latest code:

```
MyPage.cshtml

@model  IEnumerable<MyModel>

<div>
    <div id="divMyList">
        @Html.Partial("_MyList", Model)                                
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="myInputId" />
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <button type="button" class="jqbutton" id="btnGetList">Get List</button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <button type="submit" id="btnMy" class="jqbutton">Submit</button>
    </div>
    ...
</div>


//Any other scripts in this section work fine
@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#lstMy").select(function () {
        alert("select in form");       //does Not appear when item selected in lstMy
     });

     $("#lstMy").change(function () {
        alert("change in form");       //does Not appear when item selected in lstMy
     });

     $("#lstMy").click(function () {
        alert("click in form");        //does Not appear when item selected in lstMy
     });


//I AM able to get text of selected item on button click(see below), But it is NOT what I need.
    $("#btnMy").click(function () {            
        $('#myInputId').val($('#lstMy :selected').text().split(',')[0]);
        var v2 = $('#myInputId').val();
        alert(v2);    // Appears and shows correct value which is Name
    });

</script>

@section MyList{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#btnGetList').on('click', function (event) {

            var cn = $('#txtName').val();
            var cc = $('#txtCity').val();
            var cs = $('#ddlState').val();           

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/MyProject/GetList',
                data: { Name: cn, City: cc, State: cs },
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert("List is here");
                    $("#divMyList").html(data);                   
                }
            });
        })
</script>
}
```

---

```
Controller:  
MyProject.cs

public ActionResult GetList(string Name, string City, string State)
{
    MyModel mm = new MyModel();
    List<MyModel> myList = mm.GetListData(Name, City, State); 
    return PartialView("_MyList", myList);
}
```

---

```
_MyList.cshtml

@model  IEnumerable<MyModel>

<select required id="lstMy">

    @if (Model == null || (Model != null && Model.Count() == 0))
    {
        <option value="0">---- list is empty ----</option>
    }
    else
    {
        <option value="0">---- select item ----</option>
    }

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <option value="@item.ID">@item.Name, @item.City, @item.State</option>
        }
    }
</select>

@section scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#lstMy").select(function () {
        alert("select");       //does Not appear when item selected in lstMy
     });

     $("#lstMy").change(function () {
        alert("change");       //does Not appear when item selected in lstMy
     });

     $("#lstMy").click(function () {
        alert("click");        //does Not appear when item selected in lstMy
     });

</script>
}
```

---

So, how to get text selected in DropDown Every time it's selected and populate input fields?
Thank you

Comment: did you try putting it in DOM ready ?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to catch a change in the select box value is with the "change" event.

```
$('#lstMy').on('change', function () {
    // do something
});
```

If the event handler is not responding, then you either 1) have an error on page that is interrupting script execution or 2) you are applying the event handler *before* the element it applies to is in the DOM. The second scenario can occur if you are executing script before the element in the page it applies to, or the element is added dynamically via another bit of script. Always put your script immediately before the closing body tag; not only does it prevent issues like this, but it also allows the browser to render the page in a more timely manner. It's also a good idea to always include anything that's binding to elements on the page in a `$(document).ready` block, just to be sure that the DOM is fully loaded before it executes, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // put your code here
});
```

If you're dynamically adding the element, then you should bind to a parent element that you know will be there at page load, and then let it delegate to the dynamic element:

```
$('#parentElement').on('change', '.dynamicElement', function () {
    // do something
});
```

Also, the fancy footwork you're doing to get the select box value is unnecessary. With jQuery, select elements respond to `$.val()` just like any other input:

```
var selectedValue = $('#lstMy').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggestions, but it didn't work.
On MyPage.cshtml I've tested:

```
$('#lstMy').on('change', function () {
    alert("change event on Page");       // Did NOT appear
});

    $('#divMyList').on('change', '.lstMy', function () {
        // do something
        alert("change on Page 2");       // Did NOT appear
    });
```

And in Partial I've tested:

```
$('#lstMy').on('change', function () {
    alert("change event on Partial");   // Did NOT appear
});
```

Script is Before closing body tag, because in layout page there is following code:

```
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)    
</body>
```

Did Not work.

Also, I can Not put my code into  "$(document).ready(function () {" because I need to catch Every click done in dropDown to select it's item.
Any other suggestions ?
Thank you

Comment: Please, any suggestions how to retrieve selected text on each click (on the item) from the dropDown in my MVC4 scenario ?